# Can I use Class objects in Google Apps Script Libraries?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a javascript class:

```
class MyObject {
  constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    this.field1 = arg1;
    this.field2 = arg2;
    this.field3 = arg3;
  }

  myMethod(param1, param2) {
    return param + param2;
  }
}
```

I want to add this class to a Google Apps Script library and reuse it in another project. Is this possible?

Comment: Check webpack module federation once; if it can help you here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [v8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#classes), classes can now be used in Google Apps Script, either in libraries or standalone scripts. One example is in the documentation:

### Classes

> Classes provide a means to conceptually organize code with
> inheritance. Classes in V8 are primarily syntactical sugar over the
> JavaScript prototype-based inheritance.

**Declare your class in a script project and deploy as Library. Take note of the script ID.**

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(width, height) { // class constructor
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  logToConsole() { // class method
    console.log(`Rectangle(width=${this.width}, height=${this.height})`);
  }
}

function newRectangle(width, height) {
  return new Rectangle(width, height)
}
```

**Then in the main app, add the library using the script ID earlier, create an instance and call the method:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const r = RectangleLibrary.newRectangle(10, 20);
  r.logToConsole();
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably the most noob-ish question I could ask here, and I feel silly for asking it, but is there any way to dynamically get all the class names from the scope of the library being imported?

Comment: @MikeWarren I want the same. I believe I should make several functions to expose them

Answer (score 4):

consider

> var MyObject = classs MyObject { ...

in the **library** named *LIB*

this will allow you to specialize MyObject in the including **project**

> class SpecialMyObject extends LIB.MyObject { ...