# How to directly call static methods in classes in libraries in Google AppsScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, libraries, v8

### Preface:

I have already checked out [Can I use Class objects in Google Apps Script Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66440917/can-i-use-class-objects-in-google-apps-script-libraries), but that calls only one method.

What I want is to access the static methods directly, without instancing an object. AND I'd like to have autocomplete available in the GAppsScript editor.

### Situation:

I have got a library called "XLib" inside a Google Sheets file's AppsScript.

It contains one script file: TestClasses.gs

```
class XObj {
  static isValid(pObject) {
    return pObject != null && pObject != undefined;
  }
}
class XStr {
  static containsStr(pHaystack, pNeedle) {
    if (!XObj.isValid(pHaystack)) return false;
    if (!XObj.isValid(pNeedle)) return true;
    let pos = pHaystack.indexOf(pNeedle);
    Logger.log("XStr.containsStr(" + pHaystack + ", " + pNeedle + ") => " + pos);
    return pos >= 0;
  }
}

function testClassesLocally() {
  Logger.log("0:\t" + "Hallo Welt!".indexOf("Hallo") > 0);
  Logger.log("1:\t" + XStr.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Hallo"));
  Logger.log("2:\t" + XStr.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Welt"));
  Logger.log("3:\t" + XStr.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Bier"));
}

function getXStr() {
  return XStr;
}

let XRef = XObj;
let XInst = new XObj();
```

If I run the method `testClassesLocally()`, all works fine.

Now I got into the Project Settings, and copy its *Script ID*, which is a 57 chars long String.

### Problem:

Now I have a second Sheet with its own AppsScript container, where I want to use the Scripts from that library.

I have a file called "Code.gs" (default name).

I have added the Library by pressing the "+" sign next to "Libraries", and entered the *Script ID* from above. I have defined the library's name "YLib" to avoid any collisions. (I also tried with leaving it "XLib", but same problems...)

Inside `Code.gs` is the following code:

```
function testClassesRemotely() {
  // runs fine
  Logger.log(" - - - TEST 1 - - - ");
  YLib.testClassesLocally();

  Logger.log("");
  Logger.log(" - - - TEST 2 - - - ");
  let x = YLib.getXStr(); // OK
  Logger.log("0:\t" + "Hallo Welt!".indexOf("Hallo") >= 0); // OK
  Logger.log("1:\t" + x.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Hallo")); // OK
  Logger.log("2:\t" + YLib.getXStr().containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Welt")); // OK
  //Logger.log("3:\t" + YLib.XStr.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Bier")); // FAIL: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'containsStr')
  //Logger.log("4:\t" + YLib.XRef.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Bier")); // FAIL: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'containsStr')
  //Logger.log("5:\t" + YLib.XInst.containsStr("Hallo Welt!", "Bier")); // FAIL: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'containsStr')
}
```

After lots of fizzling, I got all code here to work, except the lines with log messages 3-5.

How to access methods inside `XStr` (like `XStr.containsStr(...)` ) directly? And preferably with autocomplete available in the GAppsScript editor?

And also important: how to access those imported function names as formulas in the cells of the sheet? (`=containsStr(A1, "Peter")`)

I feel like this article https://ramblings.mcpher.com/apps-script/apps-script-v8/multiple-script-files/ comes closest, but especially the last code snippet ("Libraries") is the most interesting one, but I don't understand how to use that for my purpose.

Comment: Are your questions the following 3 questions? 1. `How to access XStr directly?` 2. `And preferably with autocomplete available in the GAppsScript editor?` 3. `And also important: how to access those imported function names as formulas in the cells of the sheet? (=containsStr(A1, "Peter"))` First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Cooper That IS already the minimal reproducible example. Set it up like I described, run it like I described, you'll get the same effects. It's a very specific problem of `Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project`s (i.e. `Google Apps Script`I tagged), so you would not be able to recreate that problem in any other environment. I don't know why Google made such an easy library thing so complicated, but I'm afraid that's how things are...

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, in that order and priority. Though I've come to believe that neither of them is possible, due to stacking complications of how the Libraries are shared and accessed in `GCP`/`GAS'. The articles I went through offered some good insights, some of them I already incorporated into my code example above. But it's still an old-style method on the lib provider side, and a class reference variable on the lib user side. The `const App = () => {` approach seemed interesting, but I've yet been unable to bend that to my will...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that your 1st question of `How to access XStr directly?` can be simply resolved. But, I think that your 2nd question of `And preferably with autocomplete available in the GAppsScript editor?` is required to be modified largely because of the current specification of Google side. But, I cannot know your actual expected direction about this. So, I cannot still find an answer.

Comment: And, I cannot understand your 3rd question of `And also important: how to access those imported function names as formulas in the cells of the sheet? (=containsStr(A1, "Peter"))`. But, I would like to support you. When I can correctly understand your all questions and find all the answers, I would like to post them as an answer.

Comment: @Tanaike If the first question (access XStr.containsStr() directly) does not work, questions #2 and #3 will not work or become irrelevant. For me it's just such an obvious an default use case to access imperative / static methods in a library, that I cannot understand why that use case is so complicated. If I write methods outside the class, the whole library and projects will be flooded with method names...

Comment: @Tanaike By saying `your 2nd question [...] is required to be modified largely`, you mean the example code? Go ahead, no problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could reflect `If the first question (access XStr.containsStr() directly) does not work, questions #2 and #3 will not work or become irrelevant. For me it's just such an obvious an default use case to access imperative / static methods in a library, that I cannot understand why that use case is so complicated. If I write methods outside the class, the whole library and projects will be flooded with method names...` and prepare all answers, I would like to post them as an answer. I deeply apologize that I cannot prepare an answer soon.

Comment: @Tanaike If I have a function (without classes) written in the Sheet's AppsScript module, like `function doubleValue(pValue) { return pValue * 2; }`, I can then use it in the Sheet, in a Cell, as a formula like this: `=doubleValue(A1)`. So I can use 'local' methods like that easily. But I cannot call `=XLib.containsStr(...)`, because of problem #1.

Comment: `var XRef = XObj;` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459759/

Comment: @TheMaster Lol... That was the very first thing I had tried, but which caused thousands of compilation errors, even when running the code inside the library itself... Now that you posted it, I've tried it again, and this time it works inside the library, and I also can access it from a script in another project. But I still cannot use it in Cell Formulas.